# FuncAnimation not displaying data points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python, and have been trying to produce a gif out of some data. My data is stored in two two-dimensional lists (is it the appropriate way to refer to this in Python):`positionsMatrix` and `speedsMatrix`

I am trying to plot the data using FuncAnimation as:

```
#...Read the data from csv files and store them...
#Now create the animation:

fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ax = matplotlib.pyplot.axes(xlim = (0.2695, 0.2745), ylim = (-40000, 40000))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    x = []
    for row in positionsMatrix:
        x.append(row[i])
    y = []
    for row in speedsMatrix:
        y.append(row[i])
    print(x,y) #Here I print the data to make sure it exists. It does Exist.
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=len(positionsMatrix[0]), interval=20, blit=True)
anim.save('PhaseSpace.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

All I get is just the axis, without any point plotted. I also get a gif, but nothing displays, it is just the empty axis.

I am retrieving the data from the csv files as e.g.:

```
timesMatrix = list(csv.reader(open('HistoryTimes.csv'), delimiter=','))
for row in timesMatrix:
    i = 0
    while i < len(row):
        row[i] = float(row[i])
        i += 1
```

I have plotted the data using:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(positionsMatrix[0], speedsMatrix[0], 'bo')
```

And everything shows fine. Can anyone guide my into the right direction? I am new to python, and I haven't been able to figure out what is it that I am doing wrong.